# How to use irb to test/debug in puppet

Tags: puppet, irb

I'm on puppet 3.6.2, I have the source for our puppet repo.  I want to do this:

```
irb> require 'rubygems'
irb> require 'puppet'
irb> Puppet[:confdir] = "/home/wwalker/git/puppet"
irb> node=Puppet::Node.new('localhost')
irb> compiler=Puppet::Parser::Compiler.new(node)
irb> scope=Puppet::Parser::Scope.new(compiler)
irb> scope.function_generate_mysql_url(...)
```

However, I can't get past the compiler:

```
irb(main):010:0> compiler=Puppet::Parser::Compiler.new(node) Puppet::Context::UndefinedBindingError:
     no 'environments' in
     {:current_environment=><Puppet::Node::Environment:17836720 @name="*root*" @manifest="no_manifest" @modulepath="" >,
      :root_environment=><Puppet::Node::Environment:17836720 @name="*root*" @manifest="no_manifest" @modulepath="" >}
     at top of [[0, nil, nil]]
```

I assume I need to set the "environment", or I've set confdir wrong.

Anyone else done any testing of puppet modules in irb?

I do not have direct access to the puppet server.  I've tried this on my workstation (puppet-server 4.1 installed) and on a client (puppet 3.6.2 installed).

This seems so simple, but I'm clearly missing something.

Anyone know what step(s) I'm missing?

Comment: is there a module in the `modulepath` specified in your `${confdir}/puppet.conf`that defines the `generate_mysql_url` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish but there is a puppet debugger repl for the puppet language which is very similar to pry/irb but specific to puppet.

https://github.com/nwops/puppet-debugger

You can use the debugger to run any function currently available in your module path among many other features.

You can also set a breakpoint in your puppet code and have it load the debugger using the 'debug::break()' function.

```
Ruby Version: 2.0.0
Puppet Version: 4.9.4
Puppet Debugger Version: 0.6.0
Created by: NWOps
Type "exit", "functions", "vars", "krt", "whereami", "facts", "resources", "classes",
     "play", "classification", "types", "datatypes", "reset", or "help" for more information.

1:>> md5('sdafsd')
 => "569ebc3d91672e7d3dce25de1684d0c9"
2:>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be one of those times where someone points you to another tool. If you want to do Ruby debugging, you should really think about using [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) (http://pryrepl.org/) instead.

It's what I use during Puppet / modules / Ruby development and it's super simple to use.

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'

if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2/
  gem 'pry-byebug'
else
  gem 'pry-debugger'
end
```

Bonus: it works on Windows as well as everywhere else (DevKit may need to be installed).